# Usage of other languages' words in English

Tags: spoken-english

I just started a new chapter about nouns and pronouns. The lesson contained a sub-chapter about the international words and their plural form that we could use in the English language. 
I was wondering if it is acceptable or commonplace to use words that are not specifically from the English language in everyday speech, such as:

> Alumna, Cherub, Datum, Larva, Erratum, Paparazzo, Kibbutz, Nucleus, etc...

Comment: It will depend on the person (including maybe region, at least in the U.S.) and context, but these certainly are words many of us use in English.

Comment: Latin and Latin-derived words make up much of the technical and esoteric terminology in the English language, and others besides. They are used constantly. American English in particular is host to many loanwords acquired in the last two centuries of constant immigration waves or so.

Comment: It is de rigueur to use loan words extensively. One would sound quite gauche without them. ;) English would be nothing without its loan words. Really, all of the words in your list are English words, and have been for a long time.

Answer (score 5):

These are all loanwords. A loanword is a word adopted directly from another language. When English speakers use them, we use them with our native accent, so it sounds more like an English word than if you suddenly changed accents for a single word. Some loanwords are so ingrained that a speaker won't usually even realize it is a loanword, like data, while others are more obvious or recent, like Kibbutz. Wikipedia has more extensive information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword